# Compass: Can't build layers_calculator to compute Merkle Tree

Tags: iota-network, compass

I am trying to set up a private tangle and I cannot compute merklee tree. I followed this link:

https://docs.iota.org/docs/compass/0.1/how-to-guides/set-up-a-private-tangle#step-2-compute-the-merkle-tree

[I tried building the layers_calculator tool that will compute the Merkle tree as mentioned in link and when I try to execute this statement
bazel run //docker:layers_calculator. It does not show any error or any output.]

Your timely assistance will mean a lot, Thank you!

Comment: What parameters did you use, how long did you let it run, and how fast is your machine? Merkle tree computation is computationally intensive, compare https://docs.iota.org/docs/compass/0.1/references/merkle-tree-compute-times

Comment: I am sorry, I am neophyte. I just followed the link,  I am trying to build layers_calculator tool to compute Merklee tree (as I am following above mentioned link). I tried running it for couple of mins (at least 15min), it does not build. As far my machine being fast I have assigned it 5 gb with with 2 cores per processor (3 processors). Its intensiveness will be much less of worry if I get to build layers_calculator to compute merklee tree first!

Comment: ah okay, you don't even get to the point where you could compute the Merkle tree, since you cannot build layers_calculator... Sorry that I misunderstood you.

Comment: but generally, `bazel` is working for you? (try `bazel version` or `bazel info release`)?

Comment: I got couple of warnings but I also I got this:                                                          Build label: 0.18.0
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Oct 15 08:33:18 2018 (1539592398)
Build timestamp: 1539592398
Build timestamp as int: 1539592398